# FME: SQLExecutor [PostGIS Format] ST_Intersects() Not Recognized

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, fme-form

Scenario:

[A] 5,784 polygon geometries + [B] 2,100,000 address points

Source Format: [A] GDB Feature Class, [B] PostGIS Table

Goal:

Find which address points [B] intersect with polygon geometries [A]

Workaround Attempts + Question:

[Cannot use SpatialRelator/SpatialFilter, would have to read in all 6 million points first, then use these as the Supplier/Filter - would be very slow, takes 15 mins to read etc before any spatial processing]

I have used an address points [A] FeatureReader, using the [B] polygon geometries as the Initiator, using WHERE 'Initiator OGC-Intersects Result'. This took 40 minutes to process.

Here is an example of the log while the FeatureReader is running;

```
2022-08-20 21:00:14|   1.2|  0.0|INFORM|Notice - Performing envelope query on the `POSTGIS' reader, post-filtering spatial predicate in FME
2022-08-20 21:00:14|   1.2|  0.0|INFORM|The minimum (x,y) and maximum (x,y) bounds, respectively, of the search envelope being used are: (1346681.6345964964, 4864224.784811478) , (1346852.7337965071, 4864544.631611481)
2022-08-20 21:00:15|   1.2|  0.0|INFORM|Executing data query: 'declare "public_nz_street_address_crsr" cursor for select "id","address_id","change_id","address_type","unit_value","address_number","address_number_suffix","address_number_high","water_route_name","water_name","suburb_locality","town_city","full_address_number","full_road_name","full_address","road_section_id","gd2000_xcoord","gd2000_ycoord","water_route_name_ascii","water_name_ascii","suburb_locality_ascii","town_city_ascii","full_road_name_ascii","full_address_ascii", ST_AsEWKB("geom") as "geom" from "public"."nz_street_address" where "geom" && ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON((1346681.6345964964 4864224.784811478, 1346681.6345964964 4864544.631611481, 1346852.7337965071 4864544.631611481, 1346852.7337965071 4864224.784811478, 1346681.6345964964 4864224.784811478))', 2193)'
2022-08-20 21:00:15|   1.2|  0.0|INFORM|Reading POSTGIS table: 'public.nz_street_address'...
```

I attempted to make a quicker workaround by using an [A] address points SQLExecutor [PostGIS Format] using the [B] polygon geometries as the Initiator.

In addition I exposed the [B] polygon geometries as the Initiator, using GeometryExtractor, but having issues running the code, this is my best attempt so far in the SQL Statement Widget - this errors out as not recognized.

[image: SQLExecutor Screenshot]

*How can I get the following SQL query statement to work in SQLExecutor Transformer?*

```
select address_id, full_address, geom
from "public"."nz_street_address" as addy,
ST_WKBToSQL(@Value(lom_geometry)) as activity_geom
where ST_Intersects(addy.geom, activity_geom)
```

Above SQL Query Error in FME:

```
2022-08-21 20:30:46|   1.3|  0.0|INFORM|Executing custom data query: 'select address_id, full_address, geom
from "public"."nz_street_address" as addy,
ST_WKBToSQL(01030000000100000007000000104D3A81306934413178B4F83D9352419A873BFE236934416C89EAC43E935241AEED327351693441660CABCF6B9352410BAE8E93386A3441CFD118F45D935241FD80DCA5386A3441EBBCFBF25D935241AD8F7849096A3441BE28052830935241104D3A81306934413178B4F83D935241) as activity_geom
where ST_Intersects(addy.geom, activity_geom)'
NOTICE:  identifier "d3a81306934413178b4f83d9352419a873bfe236934416c89eac43e935241aeed327351693441660cabcf6b9352410bae8e93386a3441cfd118f45d935241fd80dca5386a3441ebbcfbf25d935241ad8f7849096a3441be28052830935241104d3a81306934413178b4f83d935241" will be truncated to "d3a81306934413178b4f83d9352419a873bfe236934416c89eac43e935241ae"
2022-08-21 20:30:46|   1.3|  0.0|WARN  |Error executing SQL command ('declare "public_custom_query_crsr" cursor for select address_id, full_address, geom
from "public"."nz_street_address" as addy,
ST_WKBToSQL(01030000000100000007000000104D3A81306934413178B4F83D9352419A873BFE236934416C89EAC43E935241AEED327351693441660CABCF6B9352410BAE8E93386A3441CFD118F45D935241FD80DCA5386A3441EBBCFBF25D935241AD8F7849096A3441BE28052830935241104D3A81306934413178B4F83D935241) as activity_geom
where ST_Intersects(addy.geom, activity_geom)'): 'ERROR:  syntax error at or near "D3A81306934413178B4F83D9352419A873BFE236934416C89EAC43E935241AEED327351693441660CABCF6B9352410BAE8E93386A3441CFD118F45D935241FD80DCA5386A3441EBBCFBF25D935241AD8F784909...'
2022-08-21 20:30:46|   1.3|  0.0|ERROR |A fatal error has occurred. Check the logfile above for details
```

Additional Side Note:

[A] + [B] As two tables in a PostGIS database with a very similar query completes in 00:00:00.891 seconds.

```
select address_id, full_address, geom
from "public"."nz_street_address" as addy,
"public"."example_polygons" as activities
where ST_Intersects(addy.geom, activities.geom)
```

---

```
8:44:09 PM Started executing query at Line 29
(1359 row(s) affected)
Total execution time: 00:00:00.891
```

Comment: Your Question is missing a question.

Comment: Added: How can I get this SQL query to work?

Comment: Your title is the only place the error is mentioned, and it's not clear how you generated it. The Question would be clearer if the question is at the end .

Comment: Realized I've made some typos and tried to clarify the question / error as much as I could.

Comment: Since 5k polygons is tiny, and the larger table is already in PostgreSQL, and it's really fast in PostgreSQL, why not just use PostgreSQL?

Comment: My employment prefers FME and very surprised that FME is significantly slower, gut is telling me something else might be going on.

Answer (score 0):

1st Step

FME Feature Attribute Value *lom_geometry* needs to be encapsulated in commas and given a spatial reference as extracting the fme_geometry from a GDB, means that no spatial reference is given for that particular geometry.

```
select address_id, full_address, geom
from "public"."nz_street_address" as addy
where ST_Intersects(addy.geom, ST_GeomFromWKB('@Value(lom_geometry)',2193))
```

2nd Step

The above code throws an error - `ERROR:Invalid endian flag value encountered.`. This is a result of the ST_GeomFromWKB() function, a workaround would be using ST_GeometryFromText() in the following sql query.

```
select address_id, full_address, geom
from "public"."nz_street_address" as addy
where ST_Intersects(addy.geom, ST_GeomFromText('@Value(lom_geometry)',2193))
```

The query above however unfortunately takes approximately 40 mins.
In this specific content PostGIS > FME for speeds.